# Any idea to archive emails in Conversations in Asana?

Tags: asana

I would like to centralize every email from (or to) customers of a project in the Conversations view of a project in Asana. The goal is to keep an archive of all exchanges with a customer in one place for every team member.

I tried to use the project@mail.asana.com as CC in every emails that i send but customers don't have accounts on Asana (and i don't want them to access it) and so they can't save their replies in Conversations. I tried also to create an email group (in Google Apps) and add the Asana email at it but it didn't work.

Any idea to use the Conversations view as an archive ? Or maybe is there an external tool which integrate with Asana that can do this ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that's interesting! I suppose that if you don't have too many emails this makes some sense (otherwise it might make your Asana Inbox pretty noisy - everyone would see in their inbox every conversation)

I think what I would do is to set up a Gmail filter to automatically forward the email to your team. You can do this in Gmail like this: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en. If you set up a good filter (i.e. sent to a group address) it seems like it would be pretty painless.

One thing to note is that the conversation in Asana will appear to come from whoever is associated with the email that's sending the conversation to Asana, so if you have a single POC with the outside world, it may make sense to only forward from their account. Alternatively, you could set up a special Asana user just for this purpose, and your teammates can follow a convention that "mailbot" (or whatever user it is) is just used to forward mail, and you should look at the content to get who the author was.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you can only forward an email to a verified address and it's not possible to verify project@mail.asana.com because the verification code is send by Gmail, it can't create a conversation...